# Uncaught ReferenceError:showProvince is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

Could you please assist?

I keep getting Uncaught `"Uncaught ReferenceError:showProvince is not defined"` while trying to load my data into a sub dropdown menu.

The first URL call to my controller to fetch countries works fine and countries can appear on dropdown menu but, when I try to call `showProvinces` function to fetch provinces `onmouseover` I keep getting the error that `Showprovince` is not defined.

I tried a few tricks like getting the element id and calling `eventlister`(see code below) and also  ng-mouseover`which angular but nothing seems to work,i want the`onmouseover` on element to call my function and load data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')
  dropdowns.forEach((dd) => {
    dd.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      var el = this.nextElementSibling
      el.style.display = el.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
    })
    dd.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      var el = this.nextElementSibling
      el.style.display = el.style.display === 'block' ? 'block' : 'none'
    })
  })
  //load countries in menu(this function loads data properly)
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetCountries",
    datatdataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i) {
        $("#dropCountries").append("<a class='" + "dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" + "' href='" + "#" + "' data-bs-toggle='" + "dropdown" + "' aria-haspopup='" + "true" +
          //the problem comes while trying to call showProvinces function here
          "'  aria-expanded='" + "false" + "' onmouseover='" + "showProvinces(" + data[i].id + ")" + "'>" + data[i].name + "</a>");
      });
      //let item = document.getElementById("multilevelDropdownMenu1");
      //item.addEventListener('mouseover', function () { showProvinces(data[i].id); })
    }
  })

  function showProvinces(id) {
    var cId = id.value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/Home/GetProvinces?countryId=" + cId,
      datatdataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
          $("#dropProvince").append("<a class='" + "dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" + "' href='" + "#" + "' id='" +
            "multilevelDropdownMenu1" + "' data-bs-toggle='" + "dropdown" + "' aria-haspopup='" + "true" +
            "'aria-expanded='" + "false" + "'>" + data[i].name + "</a>");
        });
      }
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="quickNavBtn" class="nav-item dropdown text-dark">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="quickNavDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Quick Nav
                        </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <li class="dropdown dropright" id="dropCountries">
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu1">

        <li class="dropdown dropright" id="dropProvince">
          <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Code in `onEVENT` attributes is executed in the global scope. `showProvinces()` is local to your document.ready function.

Comment: Move the function definition to top-level.

Comment: Does this typo exist in your actual code? `datatdataType: 'json',`